# Printing multiple modes from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array from where I would like to find multiple modes. The problem is that my code prints the mode multiple times, but I would like to only print an array with 7 and 8 in it like this [7, 8] instead of [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]. Can you please help me, how to fix it?

```
const array = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9];
let maxStreak = 0; 
let modus = [];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var series = 0;
  for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
    if (array[i] == array[j]) {
      ++series;
    }
  }
  
  if (series > maxStreak) {
    maxStreak = series;
    modus = [];
    modus.push(array[i]);
  } else if (series == maxStreak) {
    modus.push(array[i]);
    console.log(modus);
  }
}
```

I tried to do it this way but I need it to print 7 and 8 in this case only one time.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**
The problem in your code is that you just log it in every loop. But the final value of `modus` variable is what you want.

**Solution:**
If you move your `console.log` outside of the for loop(as I did in the sandbox) everything works fine.

```js
const array = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9];
let maxStreak = 0; 
let modus = [];

for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    let series = 0;
    for(let j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++){
        if(array[i] === array[j]){
          ++series;
        }
    }
    if (series > maxStreak){
        maxStreak = series;
        modus=[];
        modus.push(array[i]);
    }else if(series == maxStreak){
        modus.push(array[i]);
    }
}

console.log(modus)
```